# How to access host ODBC connections from within Linux Container on Docker Desktop Windows

Tags: r, docker, shiny, odbc

We are running docker desktop on windows with two linux containers, one holding clickhouse, the other a Shiny App in R. The two containers can talk to each other seamlessly with us querying data through Shiny R from clickhouse. However, we also have another database which is conncted via ODBC to windows from an outside source. We would like to be able to query this database as well, but as suspected the Shiny R app in the linux container is throwing an error when attempting to connect via ODBC to that windows native database. We get the error from RODBC:

```
Warning in RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=TPEP") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
Warning in RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=TPEP") :
  ODBC connection failed
Warning: Error in sqlQuery: first argument is not an open RODBC channel
  99: stop
  98: sqlQuery
  96: renderText [/srv/shiny-server/server.R#25]
  95: func
  82: origRenderFunc
  81: output$text
   1: runApp
```

I am looking to see if anyone is aware of a solution to this, simply the concept of connecting to a host machine ODBC connection from within the linux container? Is there a driver that would solve this issue? Appreciate the help.

Comment: I have used the `RJDBC` package to connect to SQL Server. The tricky part is to make sure the Microsoft driver is available in the `JDBC` call this package requires when initializing. Also rJava is required as well as Java itself. If your database is not SQL Server then I don't have experience to help.

Comment: Have you found a solution?